# Control to display messages in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I wanna to create chat program, messages can be displayed in a different ways, especially like in IM+ under WP7. But I in a fog, which control to choose.
Platform: .NET 4.0, WPF app.
PS: I found FlowDocumentScrollViewer some heavy, any other proposal? (Or good example how to use FlowDoc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beginners: [WPF Flow Document For Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37368/WPF-Flow-Document-For-Beginners.aspx).

An advanced example from the same author: [WCF / WPF Chat Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19752/WCF-WPF-Chat-Application).

The simplest Flow Document example:

```
<!-- This simple flow document includes a paragraph with some
     bold text in it and a list. -->
<FlowDocumentReader xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
      <Bold>Some bold text in the paragraph.</Bold>
      Some text that is not bold.
    </Paragraph>

    <List>
      <ListItem>
        <Paragraph>ListItem 1</Paragraph>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Paragraph>ListItem 2</Paragraph>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Paragraph>ListItem 3</Paragraph>
      </ListItem>
    </List>

  </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just go with a TextBlock for each message.

A TextBlock can contain multiple different styles of text, so you could still support things like bold, italics, colors, hyperlinks, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it's use FlowDocument, so it can display any kind of controls to perform my task. I used it.